# Move constructor c++

Tags: c++, constructor

What's the right way to do a move constructor ?

```
class A{
...some stuff...
private:
    int i;
    std::string str;
};

A::A(A &&a)
{
    *this = std::move(a);
};
```

or

```
A::A(A &&a)
{
    this->str = std::move(a.str);
};
```

In the second case, is it useful to std::move() the int value ?

Comment: In any case, I think you should explicitly set the int. At this moment, the value is left uninitialized. Anyhow, in the first case you simply redirect the move constructor to copy/move-operator= (whichever you implemented). Since operator= was deleted implicitly when the move-constructor was declared, this gives a compile error. I don't think the first case would be wrong if you implement move-assignment, but it would look similar to you're second move constructor.

Comment: The second option only moves the string, not the object itself.
Do you want to move the object and its members, or do you want to clone it?
Moving implies `move semantics` whereas the latter implies `cloning`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be

```
A::A(A&& other)
    : i{other.i},
      str{std::move(other.str)} {
  // nop
}
```

This is the default implementation for a move constructor.

Comment: Wouldn't this be equivalent to the second case (except for not also initializing i)?

Comment: There is a diffeence between :
i{other.i}
and
i(other.i) 
?

Comment: @Herbert They are not equivalent. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Comment: @Milow Well, `{}` and `()` seems equivalent in this particular case.